# integrating the adobe push notification in android application using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, air

Has anyone implemented adobe push notification in android using android studio, if 
so can anyone share the helpful document.

Thanks in advance..

Thanks,
Jagadesh

Comment: Please share your efforts or reference articles you looked so far

Comment: https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/forum/mobile/push-notificatin-android-1, but i didn't get any form for android using android studio